# HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: php, http, apache2

I have a problem on uploading MP4 videos to our server before I encountered this problem, I already have successfully uploaded MP4 videos to our server. I am really confused why it wont work on some MP4 files.

I have following error on my console:

```
[Log] 1409209710 (1008, line 4179)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type) (upload, line 0)
[Log] File (1008, line 1611)

[Log] undefined (1008, line 1612)
[Log] 1409209770 (1008, line 4179)
```

Sorry for my english :), I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

415 Status Means what:

A 415 status code is returned by a server to indicate that part of the request was in an unsupported format, i.e., The request was unsuccessful because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the method requested.

Why :

The request did not specify any media types that the server or resource supports. For example the client specified that an image resource should be served as image/svg+xml, but the server cannot find a matching version of the image.